# Redraw/refresh table without impact scrolling, sort, etc

Tags: tabulator

I have a tabulator table which has a column with a custom formatter which uses the current time (time difference between now and "start" field in the data).

I want to have this field update regularly (e.g. every second) but I don't want to impact the current scroll position or sorting or etc.

Doing a table.redraw() refreshes but resets the scroll position (etc).

Is there a simple (correct?) way of doing this?

Tried table.redraw but impacts scroll...I just want to trigger the custom formatters on each row without impacting the scroll, sort, etc.